# Newly stocked won't add to System

Tags: adempiere

I have add some stock to Adempiere through `Material Receipt`. There are 3 kind of products,  they are `Chair, Desk, and Computer`.

The quantity of `Chair` is `10`, `Desk` is `5`, and `Computer` is `8`.

I have completed `Material Receipt` window, the document status written `'Completed'`, but when I checked `Product Info`, only stock of `Desk` and `Computer` added, meanwhile stock of `Chair` remain `empty` which means zero.

I have checked the tables in database and turns out that only `Desk` and `Computer` got their attribute set instance ID, and Chair doesn't--`m_attributesetinstance_id = 0`

How can I fix this, and why is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You may check item info of "Chair" if "isStock" is checked. Otherwise, it is treated as something not stocked or a service. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You must check the attribute set instance id of chair and also should check the stock table which has all the unified stock in Adempiere.

I hope that will yield some more information required in solving your issue.